# The popup calendar does not look right

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit, calendarextender, content-pages

I’m trying to implement the AjaxControlToolkit (19.1.0) CalendarExtension control in a Webforms project.  VS 2017.

I have the toolkit referenced in a Master page, along with scriptmanager.
My content page has scriptmanagerproxy reference.

The resultant display shows the current month on the top line,
vertical column of day abbreviations on the left side, no day numbers for the month, and the current date on the bottom. So a square box with the Month at the top line, the current date 'Today:' on the bottom, and the left side with the day name abbreviation.  Empty box otherwise.

(I can't seem to get this formatted properly in this post textbox to post what it looks like)

---

| <    October, 2019     > |

### |Su                        | |Mo                        | |Tu                        | |We                        | |Th                        | |Fr                        | |Sa                        | | 29                       | |  Today: October 23, 2019 |

We are in the US, do not have any cultural settings set.  On another page (not using a master page) it is looking ok (like a regular calendar).

Is there a known issue with using this on a content page? Is there some setting, obscure or otherwise, that I am overlooking ?

I've looked over a bunch of online articles on the control, but nothing mentioning anything like this.

My aspx code implementing it:

```
…
<tr>
  <td>
    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Start Date"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtbxStartDate" runat="server" />
    <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" TargetControlID="txtbxStartDate" runat="server" />
  </td>
</tr>
…
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
With the help of my designer, we figured out the issue was with the css stylesheet of the Master page overriding the 'td' and other css classes, and each element was therefore given a width: 100% value.

By adding the following Style code into the webpage we resolved the issue.

```
.ajax__calendar_container td {
    width: auto;
}
```